# Google+ and LinkedIn share link for mobile application

Tags: google-plus, linkedin-api, social-networking

I am trying to an implement stack of social buttons for mobile application. I got mobile links for Facebook and Twitter but I am not getting right link for LinkedIn and Google+ apps. Currently I have link http://m.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=www.example.com  but I think this links does not work properly and it shows webpage instead of big login box like twitter and facebook. Can someone please help me to get correct links for google+ and Linkedln?

Comment: Read their documentation please.

Comment: I got link for Google+  : https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=YOURE_TEXT

Comment: I know it's been seven years since you posted your question, but can you tell me if my answer looks right?  Thanks.

Comment: HoldOffHunger - Sorry for the loooooooong delay but I marked your answer as accepted. I used some other method but your solution works fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*LinkedIn URL Format:*

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: [**Official LinkedIn Documentation for Sharing**](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin).

*Google+ Format:*

Probably not useful anymore.  Google+ has discontinued.  Source: [**Google+ Blog**](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/9195133?hl=en#:~:text=On%20April%202nd%2C%20your%20Google%2B,pages%20will%20also%20be%20deleted.).

Comment: Thanks. It took me long to thank you.